# Non-Blocking MongoDB + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, blocking, nonblocking

I am trying to find a document in a `MongoDB` collection in a `NodeJS` environment. Is there any way to do the following?

This is not working:

```
var foo = function (id) {
    // find document
    var document = database.find(id);
    // do whatever with the document
    ...
}
```

This way creates a block :

```
var foo = function (id) {
    // find document
    var document = database.find(id);
    while (!database.find.done) {
        //wait
    }
    // do whatever with the document
    ...
}
```

What I want to do :

```
var foo = function (id) {
    // find document
    var document = database.find(id);
    // pause out of execution flow 
    // continue after find is finished
    // do whatever with the document
    ...
}
```

I know I can use a callback but is there a simpler way of just "pausing" and then "continuing" in NodeJS/JavaScript? Sorry, I am still pretty new to web development.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you are concerned about the readability of callbacks you may consider using a language that compiles to JavaScript. [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/#backcalls) for example has so called “Backcalls”, they make the code appear to be pausing, but compile to a callback function:

For example:

```
result <- mongodb.find id
console.log result
```

compiles to:

```
mongodb.find(id, function(result){
  return console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: That's what I figured. :( Thanks for telling me about LiveScript, though!