# Structuring database code in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, blocking, database

Im a java programmer who just started javascript.

I created a mongo database on mlabs and now im writing the code to connect to the database.

How are database code structured in node, is there a way to connect to the db in a non blocking way?

Comment: I found this post that may help.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160709/non-blocking-mongodb-nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160709/non-blocking-mongodb-nodejs)

Comment: Driver documentation at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/ is a good read. It seems code can be structured using either call backs or ES6 promises (which are natively supported in Node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mongodb's official driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) connects to the db asyncronously with a callback.

from the README:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Say you wanted to send the results of a find() as a response in json format, you would:

- Connect the the db.
- inside the connect callback, call a db.collection.find()
- inside the find() callback, pass the results to a response send handler. (`res` object in an express get() ).

So the pattern is:nesting the callbacks and terminate with a call to your response object/MVC controller/something similar.

Comment: So ill have to write the MongoClient.connect everytime i wanna do a database operation?

Comment: if you want to keep the connection open, you can use the db object from the connect callback somewhere else.

Comment: It will stay available until you close it with db.close()